# How to check if my graphic card is muxless?

Tags: ati, dell, overheating, hybrid-graphics

How can I check whether my Graphic Card is "muxed" or "muxless"?

My graphic card is an AMD HD 8730M, and on my Dell Inspiron 15r 5521 I've also got an Intel HD 4000.

But when I use the `lspci` command I only get this output for VGA:

> VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
>
> VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 6601

And nothing else.
My Dell laptop is overheating and I want to solve the problem. I already installed and configured the i8kmon utility, but that's not the way to solve the overheating problem at its root.
So I need to check if my AMD HD 8730M card is muxless, otherwise I won't know if I can follow this guide: [AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics works](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&highlight=amd%20graphic%20card)

Answer (score 0):

Mux stands for Multiplex and I believe it wants to know if you have a hardware multiplexer (Not sure about this).

There is a lot of useful information in the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hybrid_graphics) which might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

For me I checked in the BIOS under Video. If there is an option to disable "Switchable Graphics" then your laptop is not muxless (meaning you have a multiplexer which allows you to only use the nvidia card if desired). That option was missing on a separate dell laptop (meaning it was a muxless laptop) that I struggled to get nvidia loaded and working properly. Complete pain when you can only use official repos.

I know this is a very old question but figured it needed an answer that explained how to check and this was the only way I could figure that out.